How to make a vuejs+vite project SEO Friendly
I have a vuejs3+vite project. I used '@unhead/vue' library to add meta tags for each page like home, about-us, products page etc. but when i check the page source it is not showing my meta tags, instead it shows in inspect element under head tag. How to make this work as expected?
When i researched on this it seems i have to make my project either SSR or prerendering. For SSR, making whole project to Nuxt.js seems time consuming and not sure about the issues coming up. When i tried with 'vite-plugin-ssg' library and builded, it seems it is prerendering, but not prerendering meta tags how to resolve this? VUE JS is capable of handling SEO? or do i need to switch to NUXT JS?
